# Elastic Search input analysis

Tags: search, elasticsearch, full-text-search, search-engine

Can Elastic Search split input string into categorized words? i.e. if the input is

> 4star wi-fi 99$

and we are searching hotels with ES, is it possible to analyze/tokenize this string as 
`4star - hotel level, wi-fi - hotel amenities, 99$ - price`?

yep, it's a noob question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

By default, [`query_string` searches](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) will work against the [automatically created `_all` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html). The contents of the `_all` field come from literally and naively combining all fields into a single analyzed string.

As such, if you have a "4star" rating, a "wi-fi" amenity, and a "99$" price, then all of those values would be inside of the `_all` field and you should get relevant hits against it. For example:

```
{
  "level" : "4star",
  "amenity" : ["pool", "wi-fi"],
  "price" : 99.99
}
```

The problem is that you will not--without client-side effort--know what field(s) matched when searching against `_all`. It won't tell you the breakdown of where each value came from, rather it will simply report a score that determines the overall relevance.

If *you* have some way of knowing which field each term (or terms) is meant to search against, then you can *easily* do this yourself (quotes aren't required, but they're good to have to avoid mistakes with spaces). This would be the input that you might provide to the `query_string` query linked above:

```
level:"4star" amenity:"wi-fi" price:(* TO 100)
```

You could further complicate this by using a spelled out query:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        { "match" : { "level" : "4star" } },
        { "match" : { "amentiy" : "wi-fi" } },
        {
          "range" : {
            "price" : {
              "lt" : 100
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Naturally the last two requests would require advanced knowledge about what each search term referenced. You could certainly use the `$` in "99$" as a tipoff for price, but not for the others. Chances are you wouldn't have them typing in 4 stars I hope, rather having some checkboxes or other form-based selections, so this should be quite realistic.

Technically, you could create a custom analyzer that recognized each term based on their position, but that's not really a good or useful idea.

Comment: Along the lines of my last note, you should probably make the star level numeric as well.